# How to fix ConcurrentModificationException when using foreach to iterate over a List?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

am trying to add objects to an arraylist after verifying either that object already exits in the list or not. But am getting a ConcurrentModificationException and I don't know how to fix it.

Any help?

here is the code that throws the exception:

```
List<ContexteNb> projets = service.findByprojet(p);
        List<ProjetVTO> models = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ContexteNb contexteNb : projets) {
            ProjetVTO model = new ProjetVTO();
            model.setNbillets(contexteNb.getNbBillet());
            model.setAnnee(contexteNb.getDimDate().getAnnee());
            model.setPriorite(contexteNb.getDimPriorite().getPriorite());
            if (models.isEmpty()) {
                models.add(model);
            }
            else{
            for (ProjetVTO projetModel : models) {
                if ((projetModel.getAnnee() == model.getAnnee())
                        && (projetModel.getPriorite().equals(model.getPriorite()))) {
                    projetModel.setNbillets(projetModel.getNbillets() + model.getNbillets());

                } else {
                    models.add(model);
                }}}}
```

thanks,

Comment: Try to synchronize your list.

Comment: Synchronizing your list will not fix this problem. You get this exception because you are modifying the list while you are looping over it. Change your code so that you don't do this. For example, put all the elements that you want to add in a separate list first, and then after the loop use `models.addAll(...)` to update the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception results from adding an element to the `models` List while iterating over it.

You have to change your logic. I suspect the logic of your inner loop is wrong anyway, and fixing it will also solve your problem. You probably want to search first if the List contains any element matching  `model` and modify it if found, and only add a new instance to the List if you don't find a match (i.e. after the loop is over).

Your inner loop would look like this:

```
if (models.isEmpty()) {
    models.add(model);
} else {
    boolean found = false;
    for (ProjetVTO projetModel : models) {
        if ((projetModel.getAnnee() == model.getAnnee()) && (projetModel.getPriorite().equals(model.getPriorite()))) {
            projetModel.setNbillets(projetModel.getNbillets() + model.getNbillets());
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        models.add(model);
    }
}
```

or simply (you can eliminate the outer condition):

```
boolean found = false;
for (ProjetVTO projetModel : models) {
    if ((projetModel.getAnnee() == model.getAnnee()) && (projetModel.getPriorite().equals(model.getPriorite()))) {
        projetModel.setNbillets(projetModel.getNbillets() + model.getNbillets());
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    models.add(model);
}
```